# manually printing a N-byte integer

Tags: c++, printing, integer, arbitrary-precision

What is a scalable algorithm to print an N-binary-digit integer *manually* whose value does not fit in `long long`. I know `printf` and friends, along with `<iostream>` (which most likely piggy-backs on `<cstdio>` have this builtin for standard types, but I'd like to do it for an integer composed of N bytes.

I have thought about this and googled a bit, but it always comes down to using a pre-existing bigint libirary like GMP (a codebase I am not at all familiar with) or "use printf" or the most helpful "this is difficult".

The integer is basically:

```
template<size_t N>
class Integer{
...
private:
    int8_t first;
    uint8_t rest[N-1];
}
```

so reinterpreting an `Integer<4>`'s bytes would get you an `int32_t`. I'd like to scale this to N>8. Efficiency is not really my concern at the moment. Neither is endianness (this is for x86).

Comment: I take it you need to print the number in decimal?

Comment: @aix yes decimal would be the idea.

Comment: My advice would be to use a bigint library anyway; those libraries are debugged and proven. How will you find flaws in your own coding ? It is not as if you are going to verify the results with pen & paper or in Excel.

Comment: @tomdemuyt, generating test cases of both decimal and hex representation of big numbers is trivial in Python for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Step 1: Define a lookup table containing powers of two in string format:

```
const char * const powers_of_two[] = {"1", "2", "4", "8", "16", "32", "64", ...};
```

Step 2: Write a function that adds two numbers in string format.

Step 3: Iterate through the bits in your number and add all the strings corresponding to the 1 bits.

Step 4: Print the result.

I used this approach myself for printing very large floating point numbers, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: You don't even need the table of powers of 2: just add the number to itself to multiply by 2; add 1 to the number if a bit is 1; repeat ==> profit

Comment: Note that it only works for positive numbers, although that's easily fixed. Brilliant.

Comment: A table of powers of two would be unwieldy to keep track of for arbitrarily large `N`...

Answer (score 2):

A basic recursive algorithm for outputting a decimal number:

```
void negate(Integer & number); // modifies the input
int divide_by_10(Integer & number); // modifies the input
bool is_zero(const Integer & number);

void output_number(Integer number)
{
    if (number.first < 0)
    {
        cout << "-";
        negate(number);
    }
    if (is_zero(number))
    {
        cout << "0";
        return;
    }
    int remainder = divide_by_10(number);
    if (!is_zero(number))
        output_number(number);
    char digit[] = {'0', 0};
    digit[0] += remainder;
    cout << digit;
}
```

I've left the helper functions undefined for now, perhaps this is enough.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have any arithmetic (I wanted to be able to see the result first), so I'll try @Fred's suggestion first. I can later compare the performance of both approaches.