# C++ convert binary to decimal for bit values greater than 64 bits

Tags: c++

I am using this code to convert binary to decimal. But this code will not work for more 64 bits as __int64 holds only 8 bytes. Could you please tell suggest an algorithm to use to convert more than 64 bits to decimal values. Also my end result has to be string. Help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
 int bin2dec(char *bin)
 {
    __int64  b, k, m, n;
    __int64  len, sum = 0;

    len = strlen(bin) - 1;
    for(k = 0; k <= len; k++)
    {
            n = (bin[k] - '0'); // char to numeric value
            if ((n > 1) || (n < 0))
            {
                    puts("\n\n ERROR! BINARY has only 1 and 0!\n");
                    return (0);
            }
            for(b = 1, m = len; m > k; m--)
            {
                    // 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 ... place-values, reversed here
                    b *= 2;
            }
            // sum it up
            sum = sum + n * b;
    }
    return(sum);
 }
```

Comment: You could use a bignum library.

Comment: An *algorithm*? Surely the algorithm is the same!

Comment: possible duplicate of [manually printing a N-byte integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036198/manually-printing-a-n-byte-integer)

Comment: Your code doesn't convert binary to decimal, it converts binary ascii to int64.  No decimal (ascii or otherwise) is involved anywhere.  That suggests you don't want binary to decimal at all, you want binary to some other data type that holds more than 64 bits.

Comment: Why do you need an algorithm? What you need is a data type that can hold more than 64 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when dealing with data bigger than what you can store in one integer unit, the solution is one of two things:

1. Use a character array/string to store the value as "ASCII" (in this one bit per char)
2. Use multiple integers in an array to store the values, using `X` bits per element.

There is nothing particularly different about the conversion, just that once you have done `X` bits, you shift to the next element.

By the way:

```
int bin2dec(char *bin)
 {
    int  k, n;
    int len;
    __int64  sum = 0;

    len = strlen(bin);
    for(k = 0; k < len; k++)
    {
            n = (bin[k] - '0'); // char to numeric value
            if ((n > 1) || (n < 0))
            {
                    puts("\n\n ERROR! BINARY has only 1 and 0!\n");
                    return (0);
            }
            // sum it up
            sum <<= 1;
            sub += n;
    }
    return(sum);
 }
```

is a bit simpler.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is simple: keep dividing by powers of 10 in order to get each 10s place of the value. The trick is being able to store and divide by powers of 10 for numbers bigger than 64 bit. The algorithms for storing big numbers exist and you should find one, though they are not hard to right, they are bigger than is appropriate to type into an answer here at Stackoverflow.

But basically, you create an accumulator bignum, set it to 1 and start multiplying it by 10 until it is bigger in value than your target bignum. Then you divide it by 10 and start the algorithm:

```
while accum >= 1
divide source/accum place the dividend in your output string. 
substract that number time accum from your source.
divide accum by 10 and loop
```

Do you recognize that algorithm? It is probably how you were taught to do long division in grade school. Well, that's how you "print" a binary number in decimal.

There are lots of ways to improve the performance of this. (Hint, you don't have to work in base 10. Work in base 10^8 for 32-bit ints or base 10^17 for 64-bit ints.) But first you need a library that will subtract, add, multiple, divide and compare bignums.

Of course a bignum library probably already has a toString function.

Answer (score 0):

You can readily store big numbers (in any base) as a `std::deque` of digits -- using a deque makes it easy to add digits on either end.  You can implement basic arithmetic operations on them, which makes it easy to convert binary to decimal using the standard multiply and add digits algorithm:

```
std::deque<char> &operator *=(std::deque<char> &a, unsigned b)
{
    unsigned carry = 0;
    for (auto d = a.rbegin(); d != a.rend(); d++) {
        carry += (*d - '0') * b;
        *d = (carry % 10) + '0';
        carry /= 10; }
    while (carry > 0) {
        a.push_front((carry % 10) + '0');
        carry /= 10; }
    return a;
}

std::deque<char> &operator +=(std::deque<char> &a, unsigned b)
{
    for (auto d = a.rbegin(); b > 0 && d != a.rend(); d++) {
        b += (*d - '0');
        *d = (b % 10) + '0';
        b /= 10; }
    while (b > 0) {
        a.push_front((b % 10) + '0');
        b /= 10; }
    return a;
}

std::string bin2dec(char *bin) {
    std::deque<char> tmp{'0'};
    while (*bin) {
        if (*bin != '0' && *bin != '1') {
            puts("\n\n ERROR! BINARY has only 1 and 0!\n");
            return ""; }
        tmp *= 2;
        if (*bin++ == '1')
            tmp += 1; }
    return std::string(tmp.begin(), tmp.end());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

manually:

```
int binaryToDec(char *bin)
 {
    int  k, n;
    int len=strlen(bin);
    int  dec = 0;

    for(k = 0; k < len; k++)
    {
            n = (bin[k] - '0');
            dec <<= 1;
            dec += n;
    }
    return(dec);
 }
```

you can also consider a bitset:

```
std::bitset<64> input(*bin);
std::cout<<input.u_long();
```